# Can I add paper size for print (A6)

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to print full photo size A6 10*14 but my program don't have A6 size.
How I add paper size A6 in my program?

```cs
private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

    task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Print", OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested);
    task.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
    task.Options.MediaSize = Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintMediaSize.IsoA6;

    PrintTaskOptionDetails printDetailedOptions = PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(task.Options);
    IList<string> displayedOptions = printDetailedOptions.DisplayedOptions;

    // Create a new list option
    PrintCustomItemListOptionDetails pageFormat = printDetailedOptions.CreateItemListOption("PageContent", "Pictures");
    pageFormat.AddItem("PicturesText", "Image And Frame");
    pageFormat.AddItem("PicturesOnly", "Pictures only");

    // Add the custom option to the option list
    displayedOptions.Add("PageContent");

    printDetailedOptions.OptionChanged += printDetailedOptions_OptionChanged;

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Please [do not include tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147640) in the question titles.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, can you be more specific? I see you are using `IsoA6` page size in the code snippet, what do you mean by that your program does not have it?

Comment: I added but not working don't show paper size in print preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print `10*14` Please set  `MediaSize` as  `NorthAmerica10x14`.  And the size of IsoA6 is 4.13*5.83

```
protected override void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintTask printTask = null;
    printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask("C# Printing SDK Sample", async sourceRequestedArgs =>
    {
        printTask.Options.MediaSize = Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintMediaSize.NorthAmerica10x14;

        var deferral = sourceRequestedArgs.GetDeferral();
        PrintTaskOptionDetails printDetailedOptions = PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(printTask.Options);
        IList<string> displayedOptions = printDetailedOptions.DisplayedOptions;

        // Choose the printer options to be shown.
        // The order in which the options are appended determines the order in which they appear in the UI
        displayedOptions.Clear();

        displayedOptions.Add(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.Copies);
        displayedOptions.Add(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.Orientation);
        displayedOptions.Add(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.ColorMode);

        // Create a new list option
        PrintCustomItemListOptionDetails pageFormat = printDetailedOptions.CreateItemListOption("PageContent", "Pictures");
        pageFormat.AddItem("PicturesText", "Pictures and text");
        pageFormat.AddItem("PicturesOnly", "Pictures only");
        pageFormat.AddItem("TextOnly", "Text only");

        // Add the custom option to the option list
        displayedOptions.Add("PageContent");

        // Create a new toggle option "Show header". 
        PrintCustomToggleOptionDetails header = printDetailedOptions.CreateToggleOption("Header", "Show header");

        // App tells the user some more information about what the feature means.
        header.Description = "Display a header on the first page";

        // Set the default value
        header.TrySetValue(showHeader);

        // Add the custom option to the option list
        displayedOptions.Add("Header");

        // Create a new list option
        PrintCustomItemListOptionDetails margins = printDetailedOptions.CreateItemListOption("Margins", "Margins");
        margins.AddItem("WideMargins", "Wide", "Each margin is 20% of the paper size", await wideMarginsIconTask);
        margins.AddItem("ModerateMargins", "Moderate", "Each margin is 10% of the paper size", await moderateMarginsIconTask);
        margins.AddItem("NarrowMargins", "Narrow", "Each margin is 5% of the paper size", await narrowMarginsIconTask);

        // The default is ModerateMargins
        ApplicationContentMarginTop = 0.1;
        ApplicationContentMarginLeft = 0.1;
        margins.TrySetValue("ModerateMargins");

        // App tells the user some more information about what the feature means.
        margins.Description = "The space between the content of your document and the edge of the paper";

        // Add the custom option to the option list
        displayedOptions.Add("Margins");

        printDetailedOptions.OptionChanged += printDetailedOptions_OptionChanged;

        // Print Task event handler is invoked when the print job is completed.
        printTask.Completed += (s, args) =>
        {
            // Notify the user when the print operation fails.
            if (args.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Failed)
            {
                MainPage.Current.NotifyUser("Failed to print.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        };

        sourceRequestedArgs.SetSource(printDocumentSource);

        deferral.Complete();
    });
}
```

[image]
For more please refer [PrintMediaSize Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing.printmediasize), This is official code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing)

Comment: It doesn't work. Paper size in print preview don't show NorthAmerica10x14

Comment: Can I see your code please. sometime my code will something wrong.

Comment: I try your code in Windows-universal-samples-master Printing but not working, I don't see NorthAmerica10x14 in Paper Size.

Comment: Which printer you selected?

Comment: I  select Print to PDF because I just try to print.

Comment: You need select Microsoft XPS Document Writter, Because the default PDF does not contains such size.